# jQuery item not triggering after being triggered once

Tags: jquery

I have a simple FAQ page in which each item has the following HTML syntax

```
   <article>
       <h3><a href="#"><i class="icon-down"></i> Item Title</a></h3>
       <p class="entry">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
   </article>
```

My Jquery is:

```
   $('#faq h3').click(function(e){
       e.preventDefault();
       if ( !$(this).hasClass('hidden') ) {
           $(this).addClass('shown');
           $(this).next('.entry').slideDown();
       } else {
           $(this).removeClass('shown');
           $(this).next('.entry').show();
       }
   });
```

When I click my item heading, the text below disappears instantly. When I click back on the heading, the item will not show up as expected. My console shows no error.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you considered using `.slideToggle()` instead? http://api.jquery.com/slideToggle/

Comment: make a simple demo in [jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/) that includes basic css for main classes in your code. "hidden" class never gets changed and both cases end with same result since `slideDown` and `show` do basically the same thing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting the same action each time because it never has the class "hidden". The easiest way of doing this is:

```
$('#faq h3').on('click',function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   $(this).next('.entry').slideToggle();
});
```

Hope it works for you

Comment: if you toggle the h3...how could you ever click it again?

Comment: I just removed the first $(this) line so the h3 was clicked again. Worked like bliss! Thanks a lot.

Comment: @charlietfl yes, you are right, it was only the following item to be hidden. Thanks for pointing that out, I have edited accordingly